# ios programmed browser call takes too long to run

Tags: ios

Calling the safari browser in code:

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"173.194.34.133"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:URL];
```

When the app runs it takes anywhere between 3 and 4 seconds before the browser is displayed, its not the location either as I have run this on a local site to see if it was any quicker.

Does anyone have any ideas how to speed this up?

Cheers

Comment: The code is probably blocked on something else than these two lines. Did you also try it both in the simulator and on the device? Did you try opening some other address, like http://www.google.com?

Comment: tried on ipad 2 and mini - in fact when its compiled to ios 6 its faster, but when ios 7 it can take upto 10 seconds

Comment: why have you not add the scheme for the URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes from sdk6 to 7, seem to be the cause of many issues that arise from code that did work to code that now does not under sdk7. In my case the code that was placed in viewDidLoad had to be moved to viewDidAppear - the delay in the browser starting is now gone.

Made some typos when typing into stackoverflow, but the code I already had on the mac was correct, but many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Add "http://" prefix to your string

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://173.194.34.133"];
```

Comment: the 'prefix' called _scheme_.